# Game screen turns black

Tags: android-11, google-play-games

I have downloaded Dragon Quest 5 on my LG V60 UW.  During the game there are transitions between a world/town/dungeon map and random combat encounters.  Sometimes the combat encounters are a black screen where I can touch the buttons if I remember where they are and sort of ham-fist my way through it and the map area reappears after the combat is over.  Other times the buttons don't work or ones I'm not used to pop up and I just have to kill the app and try again, losing some progress.

Usually killing the app and starting over again restores the normal functionality.

I have contacted Square-Enix support about the issue and their suggestion to me includes wiping out all my data and cache for my web browser as well as the google play store.

Does this step make sense to anyone?  Has this worked to fix issues with other apps before?  To the best of my knowledge this game does not interact with the web browser in any way.  Likewise the app store is a separate app, and I would not imagine that the game shares data with it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure if we can help further if the problem is caused by a bug in the game.

Comment: @AndrewT. I mostly wanted to see if the recommendation to clear all my browser history made any sense at all to people.  That's a step I haven't taken yet as it will be tedious to re-load all my websites like facebook, etc

Comment: Looks like a standard response for customer service, which usually might not make sense for independent, unrelated app.